# VBA date of last macro executed in a xlsm File

Tags: vba, excel, macros

i want to write in 2 cells the following informations :

```
Sheets("Dates").Range("A1").Value = Date '(today 's date)
Sheets("Dates").Range("A2").Value= ' ??? Date of macro executed
```

Is there a code that can tell us when the macro is executed ? Not the date of last modified ,  so i can compare the two dates ?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't 'a code' to do anything by itself in VBA, what have you tried to do so far? I see no research effort in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similiar on a hidden worksheet with this code on run:

```
Dim LastRunDate As Date
Dim LastRunTime As Date
Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim CurrentTime As Date

CurrentDate = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
CurrentTime = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

LastRunDate = WB1.Names("LastRunDate").RefersToRange
LastRunTime = WB1.Names("LastRunTime").RefersToRange
LastRunTime = LastRunTime + TimeSerial(0, 10, 0)

If CurrentDate <= LastRunDate Then
    If CurrentTime <= LastRunTime Then
        End
    End If
End If

Range(WB1.Names("LastRunDate")) = CurrentDate
Range(WB1.Names("LastRunTime")) = CurrentTime
```

So this just works out if the code has been run in the last 10mins. I just force a save a little after that code

Comment: Thank you for you respond . Otherwise i didn't quite understand the program . at first you define the format's date , but what is WB1? can you explain to me the LastRunDate ?

Comment: WB1 is an object i defined elsewhere as thisworkbook.

so basically, this looks up lastrundate and lastruntime which are defined names ona very hidden worksheet and hold the last time the macro was run.

It then adds 10mins to the last run time using the timeserial function

then checks if it was run in the last 10 mins. if so, it ends the code, else it updates the last rundate and time on the workbook. You then have to save the changes.

In the end, this code limits this macro from being run more often than every 10mins. you should be able to modify it to your purposes.

Comment: it has a little bit more than you asked for, but it shows what else you can do afterwards in terms of testing and checking

Answer (score 2):

By last modified I'm presuming that you want the date of when the workbook was last saved? If so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Dates").Range("A1").Value = NOW()
End Sub

Sub YourMacro()
'Whatever code the macro runs
Sheets("Dates").Range("A2").Value = NOW()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have changed first sub to Workbook_Open() rather than a macro for before save based on comment.

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't store data like this by default, but what you can do is create a very hidden sheet to store data between instances.  In your case, make the hidden sheet with a row for each macro, then add code to the routine that will store the current date into a cell in that row, which you can later recall for your purposes